# How to get value from Anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I create Anchor like the following :

```
<ul>
                                            <c:forEach var="categoryName" items="${categoriesList}" varStatus="category">
                                        <li><a href="#" id="${categoryName}" value="${category.index}" onclick="getProvidersList  (this)" >${categoryName}</a></li>
    </c:forEach>
```

I have a `Anchor` like the following

`<a href="#" id="Landline" value="3" onclick="getProvidersList(this)">Landline</a>` and I want to get the value of the above element

`if you could see there is value=3 I want to get the 3`

in the calling method I have

```
function getProvidersList(categoryIndexObjext){
            var categoryIndex = $(categoryIndexObjext).val();
            console.log("categoryIndex : "+categoryIndex);
}
```

but this prints nothing. so how do I get the value of an anchor ?

Comment: Anchors are not form controls, they don't have a value attribute and jQuery does not expect them to be the target of `val()`.

Comment: @Quentin thanks, than how do I set / get the value

Comment: use [`attr('value')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead?

Comment: @Banana-In-Black Please add it as answer so that this would help others too. thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`jQuery.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead of [`jQuery.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) because it's a custom attribute.

Comment: thanks +1 for your post and will accept the answer in after five mins as it is not allowing me to accept. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
var categoryIndex = $(categoryIndexObjext).val();
```

to

```
var categoryIndex = $(categoryIndexObjext).attr('value');
```

Comment: thanks +1 for your post this is the way I have changed the code and it works fine. thanks to Banana-In-Black

Answer (score 1):

try to use data attribute like this one,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yQEJz/)

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="myA" data-value="3">asdasd</a>
```

JAVSCRIPT

```
$(function(){
    alert($('#myA').data('value'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" id="Landline" value="3" onclick="getProvidersList(this.value)">Landline</a>
function getProvidersList(categoryIndexObjext){
var landval=$("#Landline").attr("value");
}
then you can set value any textbox means

<input type="text" name="line" id="Lline">

Inside script 
function getProvidersList(categoryIndexObjext){
var landval=$("#Landline").attr("value");
$("#Lline").val(landval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$('#Landline').attr('value');
```

If you will alert above code you will get answer = 3

Cheers!